# PowerShell Split-Job empty pipe element not allowed

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I would really like to use the function `Split-Job` to throttle or run the same script block in parallel, so it goes quicker. This is especially useful when I need to launch multiple times the same copy command on different input.

The code can be found [here](http://poshcode.org/2621) and always spits out the following error:

```
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

I know the problem is within this function, but I can't seem to solve it:

```
function Init ($InputQueue){
    # Create the shared thread-safe queue and fill it with the input objects
    $Queue = [Collections.Queue]::Synchronized([Collections.Queue]@($InputQueue))
    $QueueLength = $Queue.Count
    # Do not create more runspaces than input objects
    if ($MaxPipelines -gt $QueueLength) {$MaxPipelines = $QueueLength}
    # Create the script to be run by each runspace
    $Script  = "Set-Location '$PWD'; "
    $Script += {
        $SplitJobQueue = $($Input)
        & {
            trap {continue}
            while ($SplitJobQueue.Count) {$SplitJobQueue.Dequeue()}
        } |
    }.ToString() + $Scriptblock

    # Create an array to keep track of the set of pipelines
    $Pipelines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    # Collect the functions and aliases to import
    $ImportItems = ($Function -replace '^','Function:') +
        ($Alias -replace '^','Alias:') |
        Get-Item | select PSPath, Definition
    $stopwatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
    $stopwatch.Start()
}
```

Thank you for your help. Because this little function might help me out a lot if it would just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section:

```
$Script += {
        $SplitJobQueue = $($Input)
        & {
            trap {continue}
            while ($SplitJobQueue.Count) {$SplitJobQueue.Dequeue()}
        } |
    }.ToString() + $Scriptblock
```

There doesn't appear to be any reason for that pipe to be there.

Comment: That's correct, but when I remove it from the function it's not working at all.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information in the question to determine why it isn't working if you remove that. I can only tell you why you're getting that error, and how to fix that.

Comment: I gave up on this and in the meantime I created my own job throttle function as this one was to complicated. Thanks anyhow for your continuous support, I really appreciate it.